# Why's Google Maps showing me users incorrect location?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, debugging, react-native

According to my code, `Google Maps` shows that the location of the user (denoted by a blue marker) is in San Francisco (I'm in NYC).  Why isn't it showing the current location of the user?  I didn't include any manual coordinates in `latitude` and `longitude` parts of my code.  It's all dynamic.

How come it's doing this?

Here's `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Input, SearchBarSection } from './src/components/common';
import RetrievePlaces from './src/components/common/RetrievePlaces';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window')

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height
const WIDTH = width
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0
      },

      markerPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
      }
    }
  }

  watchID: ?number = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      var initialRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }
      this.setState({initialPosition: initialRegion})
      this.setState({markerPosition: initialRegion})
    },
    (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 2000, maximumAge: 1000})

    this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
      var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
      var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

      var lastRegion = {
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: long,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }
      this.setState({initialPosition: lastRegion})
      this.setState({markerPosition: lastRegion})
    })
}

  componentWillUnmount() {navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID)}

  render() {
    return (
        <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            region={this.state.initialPosition}>
              <SearchBarSection>
                <Input
                  placeholder={"Search.."}
                />
                <RetrievePlaces/>
              </SearchBarSection>
            <MapView.Marker
              coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}>
                <View style={styles.radius}>
                  <View style={styles.marker}/>
                </View>
            </MapView.Marker>
          </MapView>
       );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  radius: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 50 / 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 122, 255, 0.1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 112, 255, 0.3)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  marker: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    borderRadius: 3,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 20 / 2,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: '#007AFF'
  },

  map: {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    position: 'absolute'
  }

});
```

Comment: Who is the user in California?  And did (she/)he tell you that his map shows a marker in the wrong city?  Or are you talking about yourself as a user?  Or do you (the webmaster) expect to see the location of everybody that uses your site? ... please elaborate what you are trying to make.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay Sorry I didn't clarify.  I'm talking about myself.

Comment: You see yourself appear in a different city (the other side of the country).  Strange.  Maybe there is some code where the coordinates of S.F. are hardcoded. Otherwise I don't understand what's happening

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay Ah, I understand.  Thanks anyway!